# Flushing out table according to results from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two interconnected tables: one stores some general result (table1), the other one details N rows for each result (table2). 
Each record in table2 has a field recording the "auto_id" of the table1 row of reference (field is called "ref_id")

I intentionally deleted some records from the table1, but I left the referenced rows in table2.

How can I find all rows with invalid "ref_id"s in table2 that link to a no more existing "auto_id" in table1?

I was thinking something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT auto_id
   FROM 'table1'
   WHERE 'table2.res_id' = auto_id
)
```

but there-s obviously some error. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: The "proper" solution is to make it impossible to orphan records by setting up [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html), so that the database will either automatically delete the dependent records or prevent the deletion because of the existence of dependent records. Note that MySQL only enforces foreign keys on InnoDB tables, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes. Single-quotes (apostrophes, or ASCII 39) are for literal strings.  The easiest solution would be to remove the quotes:

```
SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT auto_id
       FROM table1
       WHERE table2.res_id = auto_id
    );
```

If you want to quote identifiers in MySQL, use backticks (ASCII 96).

```
SELECT *
    FROM `table2`
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT auto_id
       FROM `table1`
       WHERE `table2`.`res_id` = `auto_id`
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way IMHO is an outer join filtering for missing rows:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.auto_id = t2.res_id
WHERE t1.auto_id IS NULL
```

This works because missed left joins have all nulls in their columns and where clause conditions are applied *after* the join is made - the `IS NULL` condition means the only rows returned are those that *don't* have a matching row in the other table.

As well as being the most efficient (assuming an index on `table1.auto_id`), it also makes for a briefer query than a `NOT IN (...)` query.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `JOIN` is the best option for you.
Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 T2
 JOIN table1 T1
 ON T2.`res_id` != T1.`auto_id`
```

Comment: `!=` is very different from a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` subquery.